# Padding data for sometimes missing object index

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I have an array where I'm looping on an object

```
foreach ($product->info->details as $details) {

    $skuItem[] = $details->dtl1;
    $skuItem[] = $details->dtl2;
    $skuItem[] = $details->dtl3;

}
```

The object it loops on is structured this way

```
"details": {
  "1": {
    "dtl1": "123",
    "dtl2": "TEst",
    "dtl3": "123"
  },
  "2": {
    "dtl1": "12",
    "dtl2": "Test",
    "dtl3": "153"
  }
},
```

The thing is, it can only have up to 2 of those sets but sometimes it has only one.

Is there a way to accomodate in my foreach loop so that if there is only one then I can basically 'dummy up' a second set with all zeroes? I'm mapping this to a file and need to make sure I'm at least always mapping all 6 values

So if the object looks like

```
"details": {
  "1": {
    "dtl1": "123",
    "dtl2": "TEst",
    "dtl3": "123"
  }
```

I would want to create my array like

```
0 => "123",
1 => "TEst",
2 => "123"
3 => "0",
4 => "0",
5 => "0"
```

Comment: `foreach($details as $key => $value) { ... }`

Comment: but if an item only has the key of "1", how can I still create a hypothetical "2" key with all zeroes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the foreach, you can pad your array with zero:

```
foreach ($product->info->details as $details) {
    $skuItem[] = $details->dtl1;
    $skuItem[] = $details->dtl2;
    $skuItem[] = $details->dtl3;
}
```

Array now contains:

```
0 => "123"
1 => "TEst"
2 => "123"
```

Now run:

```
$skuItem = array_pad($skuItem, 6, 0);
```

This will add zeros to the end of the array until you get 6 items in it, so the array now contains:

```
0 => '123'
1 => 'TEst'
2 => '123'
3 => 0
4 => 0
5 => 0
```

If you want string zero instead, then just pass that as the 3rd arg:

```
$skuItem = array_pad($skuItem, 6, '0');
```

Yields:

```
0 => '123'
1 => 'TEst'
2 => '123'
3 => '0'
4 => '0'
5 => '0'
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's exactly what I was getting at, sorry for any confusion. Some times the details object only has an element with the key of "1", but I would still want to create data in the array with one of "2"

Comment: @Whisou138 this looks like it would produce the output you showed in the edit you just made to your question

Comment: Right. If your original object only had one item and you created an array with 3 values, then the pad would expand that to 6. If your original object had two items and you created an array with 6 values, then the pad would do nothing.

Comment: Ok so I think that makes sense but I found an issue. When I run it, it doesn't fill because I've already put things in the array before this so there's always 6 items basically. Is there a way to check in the loop so that if there's only one then add another set?

Comment: So there's already 7 values in the skuItem array by the time it gets to this foreach loop

Comment: You could use `count($skuItem)` prior to the loop and pad accordingly (count+6).

Comment: Not sure I understand -- are you saying that you have more than one item, and there's another loop outside this one, and you're appending to this array for each item, and you need exactly six entries per item?

Comment: There's not a loop outside this one, it's just static values in the array from the object. This $details object holds these 3 values and I need  just this loop to account for 6 values. Either the 6 it actually returns, or the first 3 and then add 3 zeroes

Comment: I was thinking I could do something along the lines of saying "If this loop returns 2 items then do what it's already doing, if only 1 item then add 3 zeroes to main array "

Comment: Ah ok. If the number of items in the array beforehand is always the same, then just use that number plus 6 instead of 6. If the number of items can change, use Nigel's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template of what you want and replace with what you create in the loop:

```
$skuItem = array_replace(array_fill(0, 6, 0), $skuItem);
```

`array_pad` is probably better for this trivial example, but consider if you have a variety of values:

```
$temp = array('x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'z');
$skuItem = array_replace($temp, $skuItem);
```

Or:

```
$temp = array('x', 'y', 'z');
if(count($skuItem) != 6) {
    $skuItem = array_merge($skuItem, $temp);
}
```

Comment: is there a way in that if statement to check if the foreach on details contained one set or two instead?

Comment: Before the loop just check `count($product->info->details)`.  But since you show 3 in each object then if there are 3 in result array then there was 1 if there are 6 then there are 2, etc...

Comment: Can you kind of show how I would use the count to dictate whether or not to add zeroes though?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.  My first code replaces six 0s with what you generate in the loop.  If loop generates three values then they replace the first three 0s, if loop generates six values then all 0s are replaced by what you generated in the loop.  You will always have 6 in result.